# iOS: Property using super class' getter and setter not working anymore with Xcode 4.4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, properties

I encountered a problem with properties when referring to the getter and setter from a sub class:

In the base class, I have a property called listItems with a custom setter:

```
@interface BaseList{
    NSArray *_listItems;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *listItems;
@end

@implementation BaseList
@synthesize listItems = _listItems;

-(void)setListItems:(NSArray *)listItems
{
    [_listItems release];
    _listItems = [listItems retain];
    //... some logic
}
@end
```

The sub class has a property with a more specific name for listItems, e.g. addresses:

```
@interface AddressList
@property (nonatomic, retain, getter = listItems, setter = setListItems:) NSArray *addresses;
@end
```

The addresses property is not synthesized in the implmentation of AddressList, because it should use the getter and setter of the super's listItems property. However, after setting:

```
self.addresses = [NSArray array];
```

the property is still nil. Funny thing is, I believe this worked well with earlier versions of Xcode. I'm currently using Xcode 4.4 (4.4.1) and I'm not sure if I'm simply doing it wrong, or if some property related stuff changed in this context. I'd be very grateful if someone can tell me how to do it correctly.

Comment: I guess the missing open bracket in your second property is just a copy & paste mistake and not actually missing in your code?

Comment: copy & paste mistake it is! ;) Thank you very much! Corrected!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple changed the way accessors are synthesized in Xcode 4.4. You don't need to declare an ivar anymore and you don't have to synthesize the accessors. You still *can* of course declare your own ivars and synthesizors, but since you don't, the compiler does it for you.

You can suppress this by using `@dynamic` instead.

There is a warning that you can turn on in the Build Settings called **Implicit Synthesized Properties**. Turn that on to temporarily get warnings about all the accessors that are synthesized for you.

> Starting in Xcode 4.4, the Apple LLVM Compiler will implicitly
>   synthesize properties that are not explicitly synthesized using
>   @synthesize.  This warning warns about such implicit behavior, even
>   though the property is still synthesized.  This is essentially a
>   backwards compatability warning, or for those who wish to continue to
>   explicitly use @synthesize.

Answer (score 2):

In your `AddressList` implementation, add `@dynamic addresses;`. This will make it so xcode doesn't automatically generate anything for you anymore. Right now Xcode is generating `-listItems` and `setListItems:` methods that refer to an auto-generated instance variable `_addresses`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is interesting.

First off, remove the ivar _listItems from your declaration of BaseList.
synthesize creates that ivar for you, possibly causing a duplicate name error.

I see you decided to override the synthesized setter...technically at least. Try to change the method name to setlistItems (small L). That way, whenever you call self.listItems = x, it will call your custom setter.

Try adding that synthesize. Otherwise, the variable might as well not exist at all.
In my opinion at least. Sorry if that isn't that helpful.

Comment: `setListItems` is the correct capitalization. The compiler is smart enough to handle standard camel-case.

Comment: @NoahWitherspoon Is that so? Thank you for pointing that out, I wasn't aware.